# need to fix add/remove rows of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

This "almost" works http://jsfiddle.net/RfWsy/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function addRows(label, maxRows, minRows) {
  $('.add-' + label).live('click', function() {
    if ($("." + label + "-group").length < maxRows) {

      var newrow = $('#' + label + '-template')
        .clone().removeAttr('id');

      newrow.insertAfter($(this)
        .closest('.' + label + '-group'))
        .find('.minus').show();

      newrow.find('input').val('');
      newrow.find('select').val('');

    }
  });

  $('.remove-' + label).live('click', function() {
    if ($("." + label + "-group").length > minRows) {
      $(this).closest('.' + label + '-group').remove();
    }
  });
}
  addRows('hs-community-service', 3, 1);
});​
```

The user can add up to three sets of fields, then remove all but one. That works, but after removing all but one set (by clicking the first minus link at very top), try clicking the add button, you'll notice it does not add a new set of fields.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your jsfiddle example, you also had a stray close </div> tag: </div><!-- end outcomegroup -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the line:

```
$(this).closest('.' + label + '-group').remove();
```

to:

```
$("." + label + "-group").last().remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RfWsy/12/)**

BTW, .live() has been deprecated in favor of .on() in the latest versions of jQuery (which is what the example uses).

Comment: Tried yours, works except when removing all sets from the top to bottom, the add+ link doesn't add a new set if you remove the first set of fields

Comment: Hmmm, I just checked my latest fiddle and can't duplicate what you're describing.

Comment: I think I fixed it, I removed the removeAttr('id'); from the var newrow, http://jsfiddle.net/RfWsy/13/

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you remove the div which is used as template.
If you inspect your html you'll see that `#hs-comunity-service-template` doesn't exist.

Fix the following code:

```
$('.remove-' + label).live('click', function() {
    var $element = $("." + label + "-group");
    if ($element.length > minRows) {
        $element.last().remove();
    }
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RfWsy/8/)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your jsfiddle code, I noticed that you're removing the `closest` group to the `minus` link, which happens to be the first group, and since you're removing the `id` attribute for that group, the selector for the group to add no longer applies. I've modified your code, which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/RfWsy/7/

Comment: I found another error in my code, it does not remove the appropriate set when clicking the minus link next to that set, it just removes set after it.